# What Beer Line or Hose Size Fits the Cornelius/Corny Keg Barbed Quick Disconnects?

Tags: equipment, corny-keg

I'm needing hoses to run to and from my barbed ball-lock quick disconnect on my cornelius keg.

- Which diameter should I be getting?
- Do I need reinforced hoses?

---

Answer:

- 1/4" (6mm) Inner Diameter.
- 3/16" (5mm) Inner Diameter, with boiling water to soften and stretch.
- Reinforced is not required.

Comment: For dispensing, 3/16 is preferred for short runs, as it has higher internal resistance. That is, you can use a shorter line and achieve the same drop in pressure as a longer length of 1/4 line would provide.

Comment: Ah, this has some important balance between serving pressure of the beer vs carbonation correct? Can you help me find a suitable Q&A to link with ?

Comment: I added this http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/11310/balancing-correct-serving-pressure-vs-beer-line-length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is 1/4 Inch (6mm) Inside Diameter pipe, but you should also be able to force a flexible 3/16 (5mm) ID pipe over it.

There is no need for reinforced hose if you are using proper beer and gas line.

Comment: I guess some boiling water to stretch out the 3/16.