# Balancing: Correct Serving Pressure Vs Beer Line Length

Tags: co2, kegerator, corny-keg, pressure, serving

How long should my beer lines be in my kegerator or keezer for the perfect pint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original Source: [BYO.com Balancing your Draft System: Advanced Brewing](http://byo.com/stories/item/164-balancing-your-draft-system-advanced-brewing)

With:

- 3/16" beer lines
- Serving tap 2ft above the keg
- 5 PSI CO2 serving/dispensing pressure (high for some Homebrewers)

A 2ft beer line would be a good starting place (but start longer you can always cut some off but you can't put back on).

> A matter of balance
>
> Calculating the correct dispensing pressure and
>   making changes to the system is known as “balancing” and is critical
>   to pouring a perfect beer. Balance is not only dependent on the
>   carbonation level and the temperature of the beer, but several other
>   factors also enter into the equation. These include the overall height
>   difference between the keg and the tap, the length and diameter of the
>   dispensing line and the type of tap being used. Changes to any one of
>   these will change the balance of the system.
>
> Between the keg and the tap, there is resistance to the flow of the
>   beer. Gravity (the difference in height) accounts for 
>   0.5 PSI per foot (11.3 kilopascals per meter), a positive value if the tap is located above the keg, negative if the tap is below it. A
>   standard beer faucet has a resistance of 2 PSI (13.8 kPa); the shank
>   adds another 1 PSI (6.9 kPa). A picnic or “cobra” tap has a resistance
>   of about 
>   0.5 PSI (3.4 kPa). Additionally, the beer line itself offers the following resistance based on the inside diameter. (These figures are
>   for flexible vinyl beverage tubing):
>
> 3/16 in. (4.75 mm) inside diameter (ID):
>   3.0 PSI/ft. (67.9 kPa/m) 1/4 in. (6.35 mm) ID:
>   0.8 PSI/ft. (18.1 kPa/m) 5/16 in. (7.94 mm) ID:
>   0.4 PSI/ft. (9.0 kPa/m) 3/8 in. (9.53 mm) ID:
>   0.2 PSI/ft. (4.5 kPa/m)
>
> Finally, some additional pressure is necessary to achieve a proper
>   flow rate. The generally accepted desirable pour rate for beer is
>   considered to be 1 US gallon (3.8 L) per minute or 1 US pint (473 mL)
>   per 7–8 seconds. For most systems, a value of 5 PSI (34.5 kPa) is
>   sufficient for balancing calculations.
>
> Assuming that the other values remain the same, the easiest way to
>   balance the system is to adjust the line length so that the total
>   resistance of the system equals the carbonation pressure minus the
>   required 5 PSI (34.5 kPa) for a proper flow rate. Round the result to
>   the next highest foot (0.3 meter).
>
> For example, for a pale ale that is carbonated to 2.3 volumes of CO2
>   at 46 °F (8 °C), the correct carbonation pressure (from the force
>   carbonation formula) is 13 PSI (89.6 kPa). The beer is dispensed
>   through a standard shank and beer faucet at a height of 2 ft. (60.9
>   cm) above the center of the keg. Here are the calculations for the
>   required length of 3/16 in. (4.75 mm) diameter beer line in order to
>   balance the system:
>
> Gravity resistance: +2 ft. (60.9 cm) *  0.5 PSI/ft (11.3 kPa/m) = 1
>   PSI (6.9 kPa)
>
> Shank resistance: 1 PSI (6.9 kPa)
>
> Faucet resistance: 2 PSI (13.8 kPa)
>
> Fixed resistance of the system (not including the line): 2 + 1 + 1 = 4
>   PSI 
>       (13.8 + 6.9 + 6.9 = 27.6 kPa)
>
> Carbonation pressure of the beer 
>       (2.3 volumes of CO2 at 46 °F/8 °C):     13 PSI (89.6 kPa)
>
> Pressure required to dispense beer at 
>       1 gallon (3.78 liters)/minute: 
>       5 PSI (34.5 kPa)
>
> Pressure needing to be balanced: 
>       13 - 5 = 8 PSI (89.6 - 34.5 = 55.1 kPa)
>
> Resistance to be supplied by the line: 
>       8 - 4 = 4 PSI (55.2 - 27.6 = 27.6 kPa)
>
> Resistance of 3/16 in. (4.75 mm) ID beer 
>       line: 3 PSI/ft. (67.9 kPa/m)
>
> Length of 3/16 in. (4.75 mm) ID line required to achieve 8 PSI (55.1
>   kPa) resistance:
>       4/3 = 1.33 ft. (40.5 cm)
>
> Rounded to next highest foot (0.3 meters): 
>       2 ft. (61 cm)
>
> Therefore, 2 ft. (61 cm) of 3/16 in.  (4.75 mm) ID diameter tubing
>   will balance this system for the example beer.
>
> (Note: This length seems short by homebrew standards because 5 PSI is
>   a higher “overpressure” than most homebrewers use. Lowering the
>   dispensing pressure to 0.5–1.0 PSI will result in a line length more
>   in line with usual homebrew setups. Experiment with flow rates to find
>   one you like.)

Comment: http://www.draughtquality.org/ – and the Manual in particular – is an even better (more complete, "authoritative", &c.) resource along these lines.

Comment: I have a similar question, only backwards -- I know my rise and my line diameter and length and the pressure I would use for a 2' "picnic tap", how do I calculate the pressure for the length of line I have?

Ex: I'd serve from a 2' picnic tap at 11psi, I've got a 2.5' (30") rise and 20' of 3/16" line between my keg & tap.  What pressure do I use?

(More importantly: what's the formula, so I can change pressure & length and get new PSI?)

Thanks!